# Track a Cell across a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, date, cell

Sorry guys i may not have explained the problem accurately. i am trying to track a specific cell(contains a date) in a Workbook in which frequently new worksheets are added. I need to check the last created sheet and copy the date in a different workbook.

Comment: `WorkSheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter which order the worksheets are in.
It does not matter what the names of the worksheets are.
It does not matter what cell contains the date.

When the worksheet is added and the date inserted, assign/reassign the `Name` **SpecialCell** *(or a similar name)* to the date cell.  Then another workbook can refer to the date with a formula like:

```
='C:\Users\garys\Desktop\whatever.xlsm'!SpecialCell
```

[image]

Comment: That Worked for me. Thank you Gary